# io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, kotlin, grpc

I have a problem with grpc. How to fix it?

Logcat:

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:165)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.examples.helloworld.GreeterGrpc$GreeterBlockingStub.sayHello(GreeterGrpc.java:177)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.example.myapplication.GreeterRCP.addNewUser(GreeterRCP.kt:34)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$addUser$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:37)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:807)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:858)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket(Unknown Source:0)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.968 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:241)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:220)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:100)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:218)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$3.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:543)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
2022-12-18 22:47:25.969 19034-19150 System.err              com.example.myapplication            W      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header